# checking ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

> $\phi: \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}[x], \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^i \to a_0 + a_1x$

> $D:  \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}[x], D(p) \to dp/dx$

Hi. I want to clarify whether my understanding is correct.

I have two similar problems above. I need to decide if it's ring homomorphism or not.

For the first one, $\phi$ is sending a polynomial function to a polynomial that has only constant and degree 1 terms. For example, $\phi(3 + 2x + 4x^2) \to 3 + 2x$ .

This one is not ring homomorphism because the largest degree of $\phi(pq)$ is $x$, but that of $\phi(p)\phi(q)$ is $x^2$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomial functions.

Likewise, for the second problem, the largest degree of $D(pq)$ is $x^{m+n-1}$ whereas that of $D(p)D(q)$ is $x^{m+n-2}$. So this one is also not ring homomorphism.

Is my understanding correct?  Thanks for reviewing!

Comment: Yes, you're right